# How can I only swap the values of two columns and leave the rest as it is in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using Pandas to create a dataframe by extracting a file which is located in an SFTP location. Sample df looks like below:

[image]

So what I'm trying to achieve here is to only swap the values between columns **PROCESS_FLAG** and **AD_WINDTOUCH_ID** and leave the rest of the dataframe cols and rows as it is. **Please note** I don't want to even switch the column names, just the values. I tried finding an approach and only came across **reindexing** which doesn't work as expected. If any of you'll have gone through this scenario, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not rename the columns?

Comment: @KJDII Column order should be persisted as shown above since i'm ingesting this into an Oracle table. Since the values that are coming from the file is wrong (for the last two cols), I wanted to switch the values.

Comment: rename and reorder based on col names?

Comment: sure i'll try that!! I was thinking since it's like a two step, doing it in one off step would be efficient. thnx @KJDII

Comment: Sounds good! good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking,

```py
df.PROCESS_FLAG, df.AD_WINDTOUCH_ID = df.AD_WINDTOUCH_ID.copy(), df.PROCESS_FLAG.copy()
```

**SAMPLE**

Given a dataframe like this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randint(0,10,100), "B": np.random.randint(0,10,100)})
>>> df
Out[164]: 
    A  B
0   1  9
1   4  7
2   3  8
3   6  8
4   5  0
.. .. ..
95  1  9
96  3  8
97  2  3
98  3  4
99  3  1
[100 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df.A, df.B = df.B.copy(), df.A.copy()
>>> df
Out[166]: 
    A  B
0   9  1
1   7  4
2   8  3
3   8  6
4   0  5
.. .. ..
95  9  1
96  8  3
97  3  2
98  4  3
99  1  3
[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

To rename and reorder:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b':[1,2,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.rename(columns={'a': 'b','b':'a'}, inplace=True)

df = df[['a','b']]

print(df)

   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  5  3
3  6  4
```